# How do I make scrollView move every time I press a button?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm doing a quiz app. I have segmented control that shows question number inside a scrollView inside a container View. I need the scroll view to move every time I press the "next question" button so user can always see current question number on segmented control.

I've tried to use this code, but it moves scroll view only once.

```
var offsetNumber: Int = 0

@IBAction func nextQuestionButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    scrollSegmentVC?.scrolView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: offsetNumber + 5, y:0), animated: true)

}
```

[image: Screen Shot1]

How do I make it move every time the button is pressed?

Comment: can you add any screenshot what it's showing right now and what would be the expected output?

Comment: I added a screen. I need segmented control to move when button is tapped. Now it moves 5 points forward and nothing more.

Comment: Well as I can see the attached screenshot, I can barely guess what you have done so far to achieve this. But I think adding segment control inside a scroll view is not a good idea. You can use collection view for the same. You can easily achieve your goal without messing any code by using `scrollToItem` property of CollectionView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to update your `offsetNumber` each time the button is pressed, so increment it first and then used the updated value in the call to `setContentOffset`:

```
@IBAction func nextQuestionButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    offsetNumber += 5

    scrollSegmentVC?.scrolView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: offsetNumber, y:0), animated: true)

}
```

This way, `offsetNumber` will continue to grow and move your scrollView further each time.

Comment: That's helped me. Thank you!